# Retaining default values when `.tupled()`

Tags: scala

In the following snippet you can see that the string parameter has some default value

```
def a(i: Int, s: String = "please autocomplete this param") = i
def b = (a _).tupled.andThen(println(_))

b(2) //compiler complains: not enough parameters
```

But as you can see, compiler looses this information and now want both parameters

Wat do (extra points if someone sneaks shapeless in here somehow)

**EDIT for posterity**: there is no way to do this

Comment: The problem isn't `tupled`, it's the eta-expansion of the method to a function. Methods can have default parameters, functions cannot.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) may be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [eptx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876535/5205022)

> Functions don't support parameter defaults. Methods do. Converting
>   from a method to a function loses parameter defaults. (Scala 2.8.1)

Printing `-Xprint:typer` compilation phase of

```
object Foo {
  def a(i: Int, s: String = "please autocomplete this param") = i
}
```

gives something like

```
def a(i: Int, s: String = "please autocomplete this param"): Int = i;
<synthetic> def a$default$2: String = "please autocomplete this param"
```

where we see default argument is available as `a$default$2`. So we could do something we should definitely **NOT** do and combine implicit conversion with compiler-implementation-dependent detail

```
object Foo {
  def a(i: Int, s: String = "please autocomplete this param") = i
  def b = (a _).tupled.andThen(println(_))
  implicit def xToTupleWithDefault(x: Int): (Int, String) = (x, a$default$2)
}

import Foo._
b(2)   // expands to b(xToTupleWithDefault(2))
```

Comment: > _"not do "_ - That should be a header on upper case and on a neon red color XD

Comment: really like the hack, I guess there is no way to compose methods then?